# How to Print Text in a Log This Way R.string.text

Tags: android

I have an application and I want to print the stock text in the string file.

But having him put it directly in the Log shows a line
If you convert it by adding an empty text with it the text is printed as a number

Thanks in advance

**Main Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i("TAG", R.string.text);

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Log.i("TAG",getString(R.string.app_language));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
 Log.i("TAG",getResources().getString(R.string.text));
```